# Global maximization of a particular function

Tags: global-optimization

Hello!

I want to prove that $x = 0.5$ is the global maximum of the function

$f(x) = \frac{(1-a)^2e^{(2x\cdot(x-1)a^2)}}{(1-a)(e^{(2x\cdot(2x-1)a^2)}+e^{((2x-1)\cdot(2x-2)a^2)})-2(1-2a)e^{(4x\cdot(x-1)a^2)}}$

where $a\in(0,1)$ and $x\in[0,1]$. I tried to show this using "conventional" ways, but unfortunately the attempts have failed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to run out now, so will write only the hint as of now. Later I might complete the details. Let me do one case here, the other one probably follows similarly.

Let $a \in (1/2,1)$, and write $a=1/2 + \epsilon$, for an appropriate $\epsilon$.

Now consider the function $1/f(x)$, which is (after some cleanup) seen to be

\begin{equation*}
\frac{2 e^{-2 (-1+x) x \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \right)^2} \left(e^{2 (-1+x) (-1+2 x) \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \right)^2} (1-2 \epsilon )+e^{2 x (-1+2 x) \left(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon \right)^2} (1-2 \epsilon )+8 e^{(-1+x) x (1+2 \epsilon )^2} \epsilon \right)}{(1-2 \epsilon )^2}
\end{equation*}

But this is a nonnegative (since $2\epsilon < 1$) combination of convex functions of $x$ (because we have exponentials, products are ok), and is thus itself convex. Now, you can numerically or directly optimize this function and see that its minimum occurs at $x=0.5$, which implies that the maximum of your function occurs at $x=0.5$. (assuming it is easy to guarantee that $f(x)$ is a positive function).

Comment: Thank you for your respond!. But, I think that there is a little mistake. The term:$e^{-2(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)^2x(x-1)}$is not convex, and hence the product is also not surely convex.

Comment: By the way, you can assume that $f$ is non-negative.

Comment: Ok, i tried to open the product and "luckily" the product is convex! For $\alpha\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ we can use the symmetry of $f$ around $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Actually, this function is a speceific case of the function: $f(x) = \frac{(\int_0^{1-a}\exp(x\cdot(x-1)\cdot(g(x+a)-g(x))^2)dx)^2}{\int_0^{1-a}(\exp(2x\cdot(2x-1)\cdot(g(x+a)-g(x))^2)+\exp((2x-1)\cdot(2x-2)\cdot(g(x+a)-g(x))^2))dx-2\int_a^{1-a}\exp(x\cdot(x-1)\cdot(g(x+a)-g(x-a))^2)dx}$ where $g$ is some continues function. This function again has a globel maximum at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. If we substitute $f(x) = x$, it can be seen that we get the original function. Do you have any idea? Thanks again

Comment: @MarkT1: I think the general case might also yield to some nice "variable substitutions" but it will require some playing around with the formula. But it seems more likely that your general case may succumb better to arithmetic-geometric mean inequalities for bounding the solution. Another lemma that might be useful is: if $g$, $h$ are convex and both nondecreasing (or nonincreasing) and positive on an interval, then the product $gh$ is also convex. This lemma holds only on convex functions on $R$.

Comment: Survit, first I wish to thank you!

I think that in the general case the function $f$ is not convex necessary convex (Matlab simulation). Hence, trying proving that $f$ is convex, is probably not a good way to attack it. 

I tried to use arithmetic-geometric mean inequalities, but unfortunately it does not helped.


Comment: Yes, given the fairly general weighting function $g$ that you allow, in general the function $1/f$ won't be convex. But to verify your conjecture maybe you'd want to restrict to weighting functions $g$ such that the resulting $f$ is concave (example, say $g=x^t$, where $0<t<1$ might be an interesting choice, though I have not yet checked what it leads to...).

Comment: the general function may be quasiconcave or pseudoconcave...might be worth a check.

Comment: Ohh I also thought that $f$ is quasiconcave , but I could not prove it. I will check if it is pseudoconcave. I also tried to show that the first order derivative of $f$ is zero only at $x=1/2$ using some basic calculus theorems, but again, it didn't work (my guess is that the solution is hiding there). It looks so simple, but whichever way I try to attack it goes wrong :(

Comment: Hello Suvrit, I thought it would interest you that I found a counterexample ($g=sin(x)$) in which $x=1/2$ is not a global maximum of $f$. My next mission is to find sufficient conditions for choosing g so that $x=1/2$ would be a global maximum. 

Comment: Thanks for the update MarkT. It should be "easy" to find sufficient conditions on "g" (though the parameter $a$ also seems bothersome)

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if is it realy easy (I thought so too), but maybe I'm missing something. The obvious condition for which $x=1/2$ would be a global maximum, is to require that for all $x\neq\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x)\leq f(1/2)$. The problem is that I can't find a "simple" condition for $g$ from the above inequality. I also tried to find conditions so that the resulting $f$ would be quasiconcave, but till now I didn't find a nice result.

Comment: Anyone have idea how to attack it? I tried to find a sufficient condition on $g$ so that $f$ is quasi-concave, but even this seems to be cumbersome..maybe I miss some trick(?)